# How does the model weights are modified in ML?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been reading this interesting link  [Linear Regression - SGD](http://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-linear-regression-stochastic-gradient-descent-scratch-python/)

and i have got question on below statement.

" The way this optimization algorithm works is that each training instance is shown to the model one at a time. The model makes a prediction for a training instance, the error is calculated and the model is updated in order to reduce the error for the next prediction. This process is repeated for a fixed number of iterations."

Question:
Is my below pseudo code  correct?

```
for each training input:
    1) Input to Model
    2) Find the prediction
    3) Find the error
    4) Update Model.
```

What i don't understand is "This process is repeated for a fixed number of iterations" . Does it mean step 4) and step 3) is repeated until the error is minimized?

Correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

"This process is repeated for a fixed number of iterations." means that you choose the number of epochs or the number of batches send to you network to train it.

When you train your network you have a training dataset. You give your network (with placeholders) iages and labels associated with these inputs (generally you give samples (input + label) by batches).

It makes a prediction for each input and computes the error (the loss function you uses). And then it tunes weights (and biases) to minimize the loss function (it does what is called a gradient descent).

You should tale a look at Gradient Descent here : http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/

You are the one deciding how long you want your network to train by fixing the number of time your whole training set is going to be send to your network (what's called an epoch) or the number of batches.

Hope it helps